# Do you need to include header files in a makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

```
bin/queueDriver.o:src/queueDriver.c include/queue.h 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o bin/queueDriver.o -c src/queueDriver.c
```

I am learning about Makefiles and I am really confused at this point. I have already written one and now I am messing around and I discovered that if I take

```
/include/queue.h
```

out of my makefile, the project still builds and executes correctly. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The names after the colon on the line of the make rule are *dependencies*. The rule is executed if any of the dependencies have been modified more recently than the target of the rule. (The target is usually a file whose name is the same as the name of the rule, thought there are exceptions.)

If you take any dependencies out, then your target may still build, but it won't be rebuilt even if you change the files it depends on (which long-term may lead to a broken build on a wider scale, e.g. when you attempt to link together two objects built from different versions of a header file).

---

Finding all the header files that a given source file depends on is typically not humanly possible, so there are a variety of auxiliary tools that one usually uses to auto-generate dependencies. Note that you can add dependencies later:

```
foo.o: foo.c      ## Manually written rule
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $^

## added later, e.g. by a tool
foo.o: foo.h
foo.o: bar.h
```

But all in all, `make` is a very *low-level* build tool, and it is typically only used either for very small projects or as the backend of some other build system (e.g. autotools or cmake).

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

I guess some people like old technology.

A make file simply saves if a, b, c, if newer than x then build x.

So

```
x: a, b, c
  do this
```

is essentially the structure.

So remove the header file is ok as long as you do not modify the header file.

But please consider some other technology such as SCONS, Gradle...

Comment: and of course CMake! Make is a useful tool, but makefiles for C projects need to be generated one way or another.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is through my university and I wasn't sure if this is still how people did things.

Comment: @Kos - No they do not

Comment: @EdHeal they do (be it CMake or some handcrafted setup with including `gcc -M`), hardcoding or ignoring deps is shooting yourself in the foot